# Testing WebAPI Controller with Multiple Put/Post parameters

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

So according to various suggestions I updated my web api controller method that accepts multiple complex parameter objects from

```
   //public IHttpActionResult PostCreateCase([FromBody]  ARC.Donor.Business.Case.CreateCaseInput CreateCaseInput, [FromBody]  ARC.Donor.Business.Case.SaveCaseSearchInput SaveCaseSearchInput)
```

to

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCreateCase(JObject jsonObject)
{
}
```

and then parse them accordingly ...

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCreateCase(JObject jsonObject)
{
    var CreateCaseInput = jsonObject["CreateCaseInput"].ToObject<CreateCaseInput>();
    var SaveCaseSearchInput = jsonObject["SaveCaseSearchInput"].ToObject<SaveCaseSearchInput>();
    ARC.Donor.Service.Case.CaseServices cs = new ARC.Donor.Service.Case.CaseServices();
    var searchResults = cs.createCase(CreateCaseInput, SaveCaseSearchInput);
------
}
```

but even after that when I test my controller using the Json object as

```
  "CreateCaseInput":[
    {
      "case_nm":"EFG Test",
      "case_desc":"EFG is a test",
      "report_dt" : "04/12/2015"
    }
    ],
   "SaveCaseSearchInput":[
     {
       "firstName" : "Chiranjib",
       "constType" : "IN"
     }
     ]
```

I still get CreateCaseInput and SaveCaseSearchInput objects in

```
   public IList<ARC.Donor.Business.Case.CreateCaseOutput> createCase(ARC.Donor.Business.Case.CreateCaseInput CreateCaseInput, ARC.Donor.Business.Case.SaveCaseSearchInput SaveCaseSearchInput)
{
.......
}
```

to be null.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `CreateCaseInput` and `SaveCaseSearchInput` in your JSON are arrays, but you are trying to deserialize them as Objects

Comment: How to pass them so that they can be parsed as separate objects ?

Comment: Start by removing the square brackets on your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON is wrong because is an array, not a object.

Try this way:

```
{
    "CreateCaseInput":
      {
        "case_nm":"EFG Test",
        "case_desc":"EFG is a test",
        "report_dt" : "04/12/2015"
      },
    "SaveCaseSearchInput":
      {
        "firstName" : "Chiranjib",
        "constType" : "IN"
      }
}
```

Hope it helps :)